# Jquery mobile json from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

am fetching data from php as json

CODE:

```
I have added json_encode() to the php database output
```

JQUERY MOBILE:

```
$.getJSON('custom/php/showresults.php',
 function(data){
console.log(data)
}
```

The console.log(data)
outputs as:

```
{'name':'Geowan', 'surname':'hiu'}.
```

How can i change it to output in the object way so that i can access the data using 
    data.name

Comment: it's json, and you fetched it via .getJSON, have you simply tried `data.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to just access the data straight?

```
$.getJSON('custom/php/showresults.php',
 function(data){
 console.log(data.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to assign it to a variable

```
var jsonData = $.getJSON('custom/php/showresults.php',
 function(data){
 return data;
}
if(jsonData){
console.log(jsonData.whatever)
}
```

or simply

```
$.getJSON('custom/php/showresults.php',function(data){
    return data.whatever;
}
```